# Highest possible diode breakdown

Tags: circuit-design, diodes, high-voltage

I would like a 2-terminal device/circuit which conducts at least 1mA at +2 V and at most 1uA at -20 kV.  Is this currently possible?

For breakdown voltages below about 3 kV (instead of the 20 kV I am seeking), traditional high voltage diodes exist.  And, the common solution for higher voltages is then to just stack traditional diodes (e.g., stack twenty 1N4007 diodes for 20 kV), but that then fails my +2 V requirement.

To reiterate, I only need 1 mA at +2 V and I don't need to stick with the p-n junction approach.  I would prefer a passive circuit, but the meaning of "passive" can become vague, so I am even open to active circuits.  Any ideas?

Comment: So people can be sure they won't find themselves working on an X-Y problem, please can you edit your question and add a detailed description of what this is to be used in and why. Thanks.

Comment: Some vacuum tube rectifiers are rated for reverse voltage breakdown over 20kV. Have you considered those?

Comment: Forward voltage is generally between 10 V -> 30 V ... for 10 & 20 kV diodes. Check this for information http://www.diva-portal.se/smash/get/diva2:1555396/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Comment: Disappointing that my question was closed.  I cannot understand how this lacks clarity, my required specs are completely specified.  Your obsession with avoiding the X-Y problem (which is vague to begin with) is hurting this website.

Comment: Found also this http://genesicsemi.com/sic-pin/GA01PNS150-220/GA01PNS150-220.pdf same limitations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1B3GT is a high vacuum diode tube rated for 30kV but conduction current is unknown at 2V .

The conductor/insulation contamination must be prestine to avoid creepage leakage of your requirement = 20 Gohms.

Update: https://frank.pocnet.net/sheets/049/1/1G3GT.pdf   7mA@ 100V implies 14V @ 1mA

No semi diodes can meet your leakage spec. I don't know any vacuum tube diodes can meet your forward drop voltage and reverse PIV.